# Pandas - Converting every hour of an event duration to a separate row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

An example starting df is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'event_id': ['123', '456'], 
                   'date': ['2018-01-01', '2018-01-01'], 
                   'start_hour' : ['10', '13'],
                   'duration' : ['1.5', '3']})
df

  event_id        date start_hour duration
0      123  2018-01-01         10      1.5
1      456  2018-01-01         13        3
```

Necessary output is a long df where every hour an event takes place has a row.  Durations that are not a whole number should be rounded up to next whole number (1.25 should go to 2 for example)

Example:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame({'event_id': ['123', '123', '456', '456', '456'], 
                   'date': ['2018-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-01'], 
                   'hour' : ['10', '11', '13', '14', '15']})

result_df

  event_id        date hour
0      123  2018-01-01   10
1      123  2018-01-01   11
2      456  2018-01-01   13
3      456  2018-01-01   14
4      456  2018-01-01   15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({col: np.repeat(df[col], np.ceil(df.duration))) for col in df.columns})

df['start_hour'] += df.groupby('event_id').start_hour.cumcount()
```

Outputs

```
    event_id    date        start_hour  
0   123         2018-01-01  10         
0   123         2018-01-01  11         
1   456         2018-01-01  13         
1   456         2018-01-01  14         
1   456         2018-01-01  15
```

This all assumes you have *numbers* and not *strings* for your `start_hour` and `duration` columns. In the MCVE you provided, you have strings.. If that is the case, first make them numbers by using

```
df['duration'] = pd.to_numeric(df['duration'])
```

Comment: Glad I could help ctd25. Thanks, @jez ;}

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not correct. The TO requires:

> Durations that are not a whole number should be rounded up to next whole number (1.25 should go to 2 for example)

But `df.duration.round(0)` for `1.25` is `1` and not `2`.

I am not yet allowed to comment. So I post this as a new answer.

Comment: Good remark :} just edited to Make sure there is no ambiguity. Thanks!